# C# To Add Total Row To Last Row Of Excel Worksheet

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I have this syntax, that does not throw any error, and seems like it is the correct code.  However, the total rows are not added.  What is incorrect in my syntax?

```
if (xlApp.WorksheetFunction.CountA(WS.Cells) != 0)
{
    lastRow = WS.Cells.Find("*", WS.Range["A1"], Excel.XlFindLookIn.xlFormulas, Excel.XlLookAt.xlPart, Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByRows, Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlPrevious, false).Row;
}
else { lastRow = 1; }
WS.Range["C" + lastRow + 1].FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[-" + lastRow + "]C:R[-1]C)";
WS.Range["C" + (lastRow + 1) + ":N" + (lastRow + 1)].FillRight();
WS.Range["N" + lastRow + 1].FillRight();
```

**EDIT**
I also tried using the below `Special Cells` syntax, and same result, no error, but a total row was not added to any of my worksheets

```
Excel.Range MyLast =   WS.Cells.SpecialCells(Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell, Type.Missing);
Excel.Range MyRange = WS.get_Range("A1", MyLast);

int MyLastRow = MyLast.Row;
int MyLastColumn = MyLast.Column;

WS.Range["A" + MyLastRow + 1].FormulaR1C1 = "Totals:";
WS.Range["C" + MyLastRow + 1].FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[-" + lastRow + "]C:R[-1]C)";
WS.Range["C" + (MyLastRow + 1) + ":N" + (lastRow + 1)].FillRight();
WS.Range["N" + MyLastRow + 1].FillRight();
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this will help you at all, but if you want to get the sum of your used rows, and if you don't have empty rows between your data, wouldn't it be easier to just use a countif formula? Something on the lines of finding your first empty cell, and then inserting in that cell (dynamically) the countif formula?

sort of like

```
xl.Range LastCell = YourSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xl.XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell, Type.Missing);

xl.Range MyLastCellInSpecificColumn = YourSheet.get_Range("A1", LastCell );

MyLastCellInSpecificColumn.Formula = "=COUNTIF('YourSheet'!A1:A5000,\"<>\"&\"\")";
```

This will count through your rows and will display the count of your total rows in the last cell.
Again, I'm not sure this will help with your particular task but I figured why not try and be helpful.

Comment: That is a good approach, I did not think about using COUNTIF()

Answer (score 0):

I would use the "SpecialCells" Member (?), here's a example:

```
using System;

using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace ExcelDemo
{
    class Core
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Excel.Application MyExcel = new Excel.Application();
            // MyExcel.Visible = false;
            Excel.Workbook MyWorkbook = null;

            object Missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

            MyWorkbook = MyExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\\Temp\\Document.xlsx");

            Excel.Sheets MySheets = MyWorkbook.Worksheets;
            Excel.Worksheet MyWorksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)MySheets.get_Item("Tabelle1");

            Excel.Range MyLast = MyWorksheet.Cells.SpecialCells(Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell, Type.Missing);

            int MyLastRow = MyLast.Row;
            int MyLastColumn = MyLast.Column;

            // MyLast.Insert(Excel.XlInsertShiftDirection.xlShiftDown, Type.Missing);

            Excel.Range MyLine = (Excel.Range)MyWorksheet.Rows[MyLastRow]; // Row Index
            MyLine.Insert();

            MyWorksheet.SaveAs("C:\\Temp\\Document_Edited.xlsx");

            MyWorkbook.Close(false, Missing, Missing);
            MyExcel.Quit();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for that sampling, I edited my post to show how I tried to accomplish this, but had the same outcome.  No Total Row added, but code runs error free.

Comment: I modifyed the code, try using `MyLine.Insert();`. What's the result?

Comment: The updated code, inserts a new row between the last 2 rows of data.  Still no total row being added.